# How do you test against a specific version when you don't have a device with the version?

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade

I have 3.1.2 device and have used 3.1.2 as minimum iOS requirement for my app.

Now I want to set the minimum iOS requirement for my app to 4.0.

The problem is it seems there's no way I can upgrade my device to 4.0 without jailbreaking.
(and it seems if I jailbreak my device, I won't be able to test IAP)

Hence, I can only update the device's iOS to 5.0, and I won't have 4.0 device to test against.

What do you do when you are in such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is a problem, i've faced my self. I still own an iPhone 3G which is still running 4.2.1 and I can down grade it to iOS 4.0 My iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4S are stuck on iOS 5.

I've used testflight to for an open beta to get 20 test with different iOS version, which if it is possible can help a bit. But getting and iPhone 3G or second gen iPod touch might help.

You can install all version of the iOS (up to the one they support) on them since there is real install check done. You might need a tool to finish the installation if it hangs on the final step, but there is no need to jailbreak them.

Comment: can you describe the procedure in general? How can I install any iOS to my iphone? I downloaded ipsw file and restore/upgrade using the file, but it says 'the device is not eligible for the requested build'. Is my approach ever gonna work without jailbreaking? or Did you use a different approach?

Comment: If you have an iPhone 3GS then getting the 'the device is not eligible for the requested build' is only solvable via a jailbreak if you saved to old keys (which means that you had to have that version of iOS installed before). There is no other way to install it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'since there is real install check done'?

Comment: Uh, you are confusing me. You said it's possible to install any version of iOS without jailbreaking it. and you said you can downgrade your 4.2.1 to 4.0. Why can't I do it?

Comment: Apple will sign any install starting with iOS 4. iOS 3 is no longer singed for install thus really needing some hack to install it. iOS 4.* will get signed by apple if you install it on device. Start with the iPhone 3GS the key that signed the install will be need to get iOS installed. Apple keep track of the version installed on your device thus only making it possible to get the latest iOS. If you want to go a version you will need the install keys. Which you could only get when you first installed that version.

Comment: You can only install all version on iPhone 3G not iPhone 3GS, 4 or 4S since does use the install keys from the apple server.

Comment: First and second only, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I haven't tried doing what you're doing but I get all my updates from http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/ and he has the 4.0 updates for your device as well. Not sure about the 'install keys' from the apple server though - but you've nothing to lose by trying.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to buy an old used iOS device running the old OS version which you want to test against.  You could sell your other test device with an unusable OS version to help pay for it.